# Import error for "enum" in Ubuntu with python 3.6

Tags: python, ubuntu, enums, kinect-v2

I am trying to import "enum" but I get a import error saying it cant find it.
But it is there.

```
(cvnano) joev2@joev2-desktop:~/pylibfreenect2$ sudo python 
selective_streams.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "selective_streams.py", line 8, in 
<module>
    from pylibfreenect2 import Freenect2, 
SyncMultiFrameListener
  File 
"/home/joev2/pylibfreenect2/pylibfreenect2/__i n it__.py", line 15, in 
<module>
   import enum
ImportError: No module named enum
```

but when  I do this it shows its there

```
(cvnano) joev2@joev2-desktop:~/pylibfreenect2$ python
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from enum import IntEnum
>>>
```

Any Ideas?
I am Working in a .virtual environment if that helps.

Comment: `sudo python` may be calling a different version of Python than plain `python`.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [virtualenv docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/):

> "If you directly run a script or the
>    python interpreter from the virtualenv’s bin/ directory
>    (e.g. path/to/ENV/bin/pip or /path/to/ENV/bin/python-script.py) then sys.path
>    will automatically be set to use the Python libraries associated with the
>    virtualenv"

Therefore, if you run set an explicit path to your virtualenv's python executable:

```
sudo /path/to/ENV/bin/python selective_streams.py
```

then you'll run your virtualenv's Python with sudo privileges.

There is one [caveat](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/), however:

> ... unlike the activation scripts, the environment variables PATH and
>     VIRTUAL_ENV will not be modified. This means that if your Python script uses
>     e.g. subprocess to run another Python script (e.g. via a #!/usr/bin/env python
>     shebang line) the second script may not be executed with the same Python
>     binary as the first nor have the same libraries available to it. To avoid this
>     happening your first script will need to modify the environment variables in
>     the same manner as the activation scripts, before the second script is
>     executed.